# React update state within a method and passing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to update the state in a method start() and then passing the state's value to MyComponent. 
My component works ok, and the state updates ok when I'm setting it within the class, but when I'm trying to pass it from start method - it doesn't work. getting "TypeError: this.setState is not a function"

Edited - fixed binding but something still doesn't work.

What can be the problem?

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: false
    }
    this.start= this.start.bind(this)

  }

  start() {
    this.setState({ val: true })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Button 
        title='start' 
        onPress={this.start}>
        </Button>

        <MyComponent value={this.state.val}> </MyComponent>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this is MyComponent:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.state={}
         this.state.custum={
            backgroundColor: 'red'
         }
         let intervalid;
         if (this.props.value){
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState( {
                    custum:{
                        backgroundColor: 'green'
                    }
                    })
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState( {
                    custum:{
                        backgroundColor: 'red'
                    }
                    })
            }, 2000);
        }
     }    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.old, this.state.custum]}> 
            </View>
        );
      }
    }  
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        old:{
          padding: 5,
          height: 80,
          width: 80,  
          borderRadius:160,    

        },
    })
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: It sounds like you're having an issue when calling `start` as an event handler (ie. when you click the button). The problem is related to the context in which the method is called - basically, when `start` is called via an event handler, `this` does not refer to the component. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/2008384) for a detailed discussion

Comment: The problem is event handler binding; many, many dupes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the context to your function.

```
 constructor (props){
      super(props);
        this.state = {
        val: false
    }
    this.start = this.start.bind(this)
  }
```

or just you can an arrow function, without binding

```
 start = () => {
     this.setState({ val: true })
 }
```

Comment: fixed, still doesn't work, I uploaded MyComponent code, what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the method with `this`. Just add

`this.start = this.start.bind(this)`

after `this.state` in the `constructor`.

EDIT

And also try to move `custom` inside `state` in MyComponent like this:

```
this.state={
  custum: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
}
```

and remove

```
this.state.custum={
 backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

As you can't just set state like this.

Comment: fixed, still doesn't work, I uploaded MyComponent code, what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

bind start method to the component other 'this' will be undefined for the start function

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: false
    }
    this.start = this.start.bind(this)
  }

  start() {
    this.setState({ val: true })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Button 
        title='start' 
        onPress={this.start}>
        </Button>

        <MyComponent value={this.state.val}> </MyComponent>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: fixed, still doesn't work, I uploaded MyComponent code, what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make start function to be binded through constructor or ES6 arrow function.

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: false
    }
  }

  start = () => {
    this.setState({ val: true })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Button 
        title='start' 
        onPress={this.start}>
        </Button>

        <MyComponent value={this.state.val}> </MyComponent>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: fixed, still doesn't work, I uploaded MyComponent code, what can cause the problem?

Comment: That should fix your problem. If not, what other error message can you see?